# Can we say "majority" to the largest portion when it comprises less than 50% of the whole?

Tags: word-usage

Consider these two pie charts:

[image]

Suppose these pie charts show the age profile of the attendees in a class where "a", "b", and "c" represent age groups of 20 to 25, 25 to 30, and 30 to 35, respectively.

For the first pie chart I can definitely say:

> The *majority* of students in the class are between 30 and 35.

What about the second pie chart? In the second pie chart the largest portion is less than 50%. Can I still consider the group "c" as majority in it?

Based on the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/majority) it seems ambiguous:(1) the larger number or part of something, (2) more than half of a total number or amount.

Comment: In the world of U.S. politics a *plurality* is the largest piece of pie in a pie where no slice is bigger than 50% (2nd pie 45%) but only a slice bigger than half would be called a *majority* (1st pie 63%).  I am not sure if this distinction is used outside of U.S. politics.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther I think in the UK we are more likely to call it a relative majority but I do not have any evidence for whether people understand plurality.

Comment: Majority cannot be used, as by definition it is more than 50%. You can use "major" however, as in "major chunk", "major portion" etc.

Comment: Have you checked any dictionaries or other resources? Have you found any that say a majority can mean half or less than half?

Comment: @gotube Yes and it seems ambiguous. Cambridge dictionary: (1) the larger number or part of something, (2) more than half of a total number or amount

Comment: @alireza The "*larg**er***" means that definition only applies when comparing two things, which is true. If there's more than two things being compared, then a majority means more than 50%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between **a** majority, and **the** majority.

You couldn't say that less than 50% of the students was **the** majority of the students; however, you could say that the number was **a** majority in terms of what they represent.

A good example can be found in British politics where **the** majority of people in the UK did not vote for the current government, but the political party gained power because the rest of the votes were split and they gained **a** majority.

Answer (score 0):

In technical language, as might be appropriate for a discussion about statistics you could say that a **plurality** was in group *c*.

In casual conversation you might use "majority" but you'd be more likely to say "c was the most popular choice", or some similar description.